# Is there a way to find out whether the Metro UI panels are visible in Windows 10?

Tags: winapi, windows-10, windows-10-universal

In Windows 10 there are several menus/panels that can be opened from the task bar, such as "action center" and "volume panel" etc. Those windows are not enumerated if I try to use `EnumWindows()`, I found a workaround -- instead of using `EnumWindows()`, I used `FinWindowEx()`, and now I'm able to enumerate those panels and other Metro UI specific menus.

The only problem is that I cannot identify whether they are visible or not. If I try to call `IsWindowVisible()` and pass "action center" `HWND` as an argument, the function always returns `TRUE`. The same result I've got for other Metro UI panels (battery usage panel, volume panel, search panel and so on).

Comment: Why don't you ask about the real problem you are trying to solve instead of asking about your solution?

Comment: I think the question is a bit convoluted, but it probably has to be because it provides more background to what ScienceSE is trying to achieve. Also it fills in the requirement of showing effort and "what have you tried so far" in questions. He/she found the windows, but is trying to learn if they're actually visible. This is a valid question (that I have no answer to unfortunately).

Comment: @ScienceSE - can you provide a little bit more background as to why you'd need that information? Data points like that sometimes help engineers who create these APIs decide whether they should help you or expose/document APIs that would make it possible to achieve what you need.

Comment: @IInspectable, but that's a real problem I have, I had many issues with those windows 10 panels (they're not enumerated in a normal way, so I had to use a workaround), and I cannot identify whether they're visible or not.

Comment: @FilipSkakun, I capture a screen, but then I have to remove from screen windows 10 specific panels such as start menu, action center etc, if they're visible (i.e. I have to fill the rectangle which corresponds to the window's geometry).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just found a solution. As there has been no answers so far, I would consider it as a best solution (at the moment I don't know other ways to solve the issue).

So basically in order to identify whether the window is visible, I call  `DwmGetWindowAttribute()` function (in addition to `IsWindowVisible()`) passing `DWMA_CLOAKED` as the 2nd argument. This attribute is set to `0` when those Windows 10 specific panels are visible on the screen.